# Change number of CPUs in VirtualBox is disabled

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

I'm using virtualbox with Kali and it's working fine, however I currently only have it using 1 cpu and I'd like to add more.

However when I go to Settings → System → Processor the fields are greyed out and I can't change number of processors (this happens even when kali isn't running). Any help is appreciated

Comment: restart, close all processes related to virtualbox of vbox and then open vbox and then try to change.

Answer (score 9):

You can find the workaround here: [How do I enable multiple cores in my virtual enviroment?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365615/how-do-i-enable-multiple-cores-in-my-virtual-enviroment).

> To enable more than 1 CPU in your VM the following settings are needed in addition:
>
> - *64-bit* virtual guest hardware in *General settings* tab (for 64-bit guests)
> - *Enable I/O APIC* in the *Motherboard settings* tab
> - *Enable hardware virtualization (VT-x/AMD-V)* in the *Acceleration* tab
>
> Note that if your run your VM on all cores available you may experience a better host performance when assigning an execution cap to the CPU.

You won't be able to edit the CPU count while the VM is running or has a saved state, so make sure that it is in the powered off state.

Comment: What if the accelaration tab is grayed out too ?

Answer (score 1):

When Kali VM is shut down, you should be able to add CPU cores:

```
Settings → System → Processor
```

Checked on Virtual Box v. 6.1.40

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue: I could not change the number of processors or the amount of RAM after I had run a new VM and installed a host OS.

The only way I found was to create a brand new virtual machine using all the new settings I want and then instead of creating a new virtual hard drive just link the drives from the first VM. As long as you make the MAC address the same as the old one it all works.